# Bottle / SimpleTemplate - Call python function from a template

Tags: python, bottle

I have the following python code using Bottle framework:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bottle import route, request, template

def foo(number):
    return [number,number+1,number+2]

@route('/test')
def test():
        return template('test')
```

And the template `test`:

```
Lorem Ipsum
% for item in foo(2):
  <li>item</li>
% end
```

But I get `NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`

Is it possible in Simple Template to call external python functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test.tpl

```
Lorem Ipsum
% from foo import foo
% for item in foo(2):
  <li>item</li>
% end
```

foo.py

```
def foo(number):
    return [number, number + 1, number + 2]
```

test.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bottle import route, template, run
@route('/')
def test():
    return template('test')
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

You can import any module in bottle template. In the above sample code, I've moved function foo to other file and imported that.

[image: Demo]